# Fetching Image Id from Iphone Photo Album

Tags: iphone

I need the imageid of the images that are stored in photo album. How can i achieve it? I have heard that PLPhotoLibrary helps in fetching the id, but because it is a private framework, app store does not allow it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using the App Store to distribute your app, you'll just have to settle with the fact that this is private API and you can't get the IDs of photo's in the photo library.

Comment: will app store approve the application if we fetch the DCIM folder of the iPhone?

Comment: You won't be able to get access to the DCIM folder on the iPhone without using private APIs. Your app is in a sandbox and you're not allowed (or not able) to access anything outside the sandbox. If you try to access folders outside the sandbox, your app will not be approved.

Comment: If you need to use photos from the photo library, use `UIImagePickerController`.